# Understanding conditional statement in logic

Tags: logic

Here is a proposition,
**if you have current password, then you can log in into network.**
This proposition is false only for one condition, when you have current password, but cannot log into network. But for the true cases, when you do not have current password, you can log into network, proposition is true. But, how can it be? without current password, how can you log into network, this should be false. Can someone explain what I am missing here. If yes, then please also suggest some good place to learn about the conditional statements more deeply.

Comment: Let 'you have current password' be $p$, and 'you can log in into network' be $q$. If in fact you do not have the password ($\neg p$), then $p\rightarrow q$ is always true. Whether $p$ is true or not would not affect the original proposition, which is always $p\rightarrow q$.

Answer (score 0):

We’re usually introduced to the conditional with reference to “if/then” in English. Unfortunately, for most meanings of “if/then”, this analogy breaks down. If I were you, if unsure, I would stick to the definition of the conditional using truth tables. Why do we like the conditional then? Because it makes doing logic a lot nicer. Somehow it’s the right tool for a lot of jobs that would be more complex without it. For example, it’s really good for talking about proofs because it does reflect the natural usage of “if/then” when referring to proofs. If I can write a proof of $q$ from the assumption $p$, then I don’t think anyone would object to me saying “if I can prove $p$, then I can prove $q$”. If proof reflects truth, this becomes “if $p$, then $q$”, even if it’s impossible to prove $p$ in my system, perhaps because it’s untrue. This is unsurprising given that formal logic emerged to make mathematical proofs more rigourous.